# Confusing wrapAll in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

I have several p inside several li as below and also as https://jsfiddle.net/y5zn538e/

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p> Hello 1</p>
    <p> Hello 2</p>
    <p> Hello 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p> Hello 4</p>
    <p> Hello 5</p>
    <p> Hello 6</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to wrap a div such that it wraps like the 2nd below

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p> Hello </p>
    <div>
      <p> Hello </p>
      <p> Hello </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p> Hello </p>
    <div>
      <p> Hello </p>
      <p> Hello </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried like below:

```
 $('ul li >p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

However, that seem to not working.. I mean all it does it take all p and wrap it. I want to be wrapp a div inside each li ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is, `li > p:not(:first-child)` it collects all child p tags except the first child.
>
> so You need to use `.each()` function iterate to all `li`.

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
  $(this).find('p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div></div>'); 
});
```

```js
  $('ul li').each(function(){
       $(this).find('p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div></div>'); 
     });
```

```css
div{
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>
         <p> Hello 1</p> 
         <p> Hello 2</p > 
         <p> Hello 3</p> 
      </li> 
      <li>
         <p> Hello 4</p> 
         <p> Hello 5</p > 
         <p> Hello 6</p> 
      </li> 
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.each()` to iterate over each `<li>` and then manipulate its children `<p>`

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    $('> p:not(:first-child)',this).wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5zn538e/2/)**

---

*Why your code didn't work?*

`$('ul li >p:not(:first-child)')` gets a collection of all `<p>` which are not first child of their parent. Then it wraps them in `<div>`. This collection does not consider separate `<li>` parents.